# Is possible to combine SIMPLE values and MULTIVALUEs in conditions when you are doing a SELECT on UniVerse Database with UNNEST

Tags: c#

From Universe prompt I run my command

```
 > SELECT  SUM(MONTREMB),SUM(MONTCAP),SUM(MONTINT) FROM UNNEST TAVANCE.001 ON AVA_ASS  WHERE ETAT =1  AND  MAXDTEREMB >= '2019-01-01'  AND MAXDTEREMB  <= '2019-02-15' AND MONTREMB = 0;
```

And I get totals

```
SUM ( MONTREMB )    SUM ( MONTCAP )    SUM ( MONTINT )

               0            -599300            2144637
```

This is my table DICT TAVANCE.001

```
  Field.........    Field.    Field........    Conversion..    Column.........    Output    Depth &
Name..........    Number    Definition...    Code........    Heading........    Format    Assoc..

@ID               D    0                                     TAVANCE.001        10L       S
KEYCREDIT         D    0                                     KEYCREDIT          15L       S
ETAT              D    1                                     ETAT               1R        S
MATRICULE         D    2                                     MATRICULE          12L       S
MONTANT           D    3                                     MONTANT            12R       S
INTERET           D    4                                     INTERET            2R        S
DUREE             D    6                                     DUREE              2R        S
DTEAVANCE         D    7                     D/E             DTEAVANCE          10L       S
MENSUALITE        D    9                                     MENSUALITE         12R       S
DTEREMB           D   10                     D/E             DTEREMB            10L       M AVA_A
                                                                                          SS
PERIORMBT         D   10                                     PERIORMBT          20R       S
MONTREMB          D   11                                     MONTREMB           12R       M AVA_A
                                                                                          SS
MONTINT           D   12                                     MONTINT            12R       M AVA_A
                                                                                          SS
MONTCAP           D   14                                     MONTCAP            12R       M AVA_A
I.NOM             I         TRANS(TSIGNAG                    I.NOM              40L       S
                            PE.031,MATRIC
                            ULE,NOM,'X')
AVA_ASS           PH        DTEREMB
                            MONTREMB
@SELECT           PH        MATRICULE
                            I.NOM MONTANT
                            RBTCAP
                            DTEAVANCE
                            ETAT PMT
@EMPTY.NULL       X

25 records listed.
```

In the condition of my select command,  ETAT and MAXDTEREMB  are simple value but MONTREMB  is multivalue

The problem is that in my c# problem with the same SELECT command

```
    if (checkInteret.Checked == true)
    sRequete = "SELECT  SUM(MONTREMB),SUM(MONTCAP),SUM(MONTINT) FROM UNNEST " + tableGroupe + " ON AVA_ASS  WHERE (ETAT <> 1 AND ETAT <> 2)  AND DTEREMB <= '" + sDateFin + "' AND MONTREMB = 0 "; 

 U2DataAdapter da = new U2DataAdapter(sRequete, con);
  DataSet ds = new DataSet();
  da.Fill(ds, "TAVANCE");
  con.Close();
  con.Open();
  tAvance = null;
  tAvance = ds.Tables["TAVANCE"];
```

With tavance.rows.count, not result is displayed. Is there an error in my SELECT command.

For more details, I'm using U2toolkit for .Net to connect to Universe database

```
    using U2.Data.Client;

  U2Connection con = new U2Connection();
  UniSession session = null;
  U2ConnectionStringBuilder conn_str = new U2ConnectionStringBuilder();
  string UserId = "root";
  string PassWord = "xxxxxx";
  string server = "192.xxxxx";
  string Database = "LACCOUNT";
  string ServerType = "UNIVERSE";

 conn_str.UserID = UserId;
  conn_str.Password = PassWord;
  conn_str.Server = server;
  conn_str.Database = Database;
  conn_str.FirstNormalForm = false;
  conn_str.ExpandMultiValueRows = true;
  conn_str.ServerType = ServerType;
  conn_str.Connect_Timeout = 1200;
  con.ConnectionString = conn_str.ToString();
  con.Open();
```